# How to zoom in the environment to view the menu bar

Tags: 18.04, fonts, 20.04, dpi

Any help is appreciated! I am experiencing this problem with quite a few applications on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, where the general menu bar for the application (for example: Notepad++), where we have options like file,edit, tools etc., is very tiny in its font. I already tried applying (Ctrl +) to zoom in, but that only affects the text on screen and doesn't affect the menu itself.

I am a new user to Ubuntu, recently downloaded 18.04 and upgraded to 20.04 on my Dell XPS13 9360. Do let me know if there is a solution to enlarge these options. I generally experience this issue with apps like Spotify, Notepad++, and recently downloaded Stream and experienced the same issue.

I am wondering if there is a way to view all the options on the top bar near the Activities, (like in Mac) or if there is just a way to enlarge and scale it to fit properly.

Please see the screenshot of the issue to better understand it.

[image: A screenshot of Notepad++]

Comment: I suppose that the issue is the same as in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552875/notepad-installed-through-snap-install-has-a-menu-bar-with-very-small-letter). Can you give a try at what the answer suggests?

Comment: @user3140225 I tried the advise on that question, but I get an error as follows:

**cp: cannot stat '/home/hemantsriram/.wine/user.reg': No such file or directory**

they ask to copy the .reg files to this, I have installed Ubuntu instead of my Windows, so I am assuming I won't have the *.reg files pre-installed. But that solution is only for Notepad ++, I'm assuming Ubuntu has a universal solution that can be applied?

Comment: It might be one of the options in Tweak. Click on the pattern of dots in the bottom left corner of the home screen and then type tweak into the search bar. Start the tweak application from its icon. Try each font size option until you one that does what you want. Revert each one before you try another.

Comment: @SteveRoome Unfortuateyl it's not one of the options on Tweaks menu, that was the first thing I tried after searching for answers. But now I have given up on using it completely and just installed other IDEs for coding